# Spring Boot JMX ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, groovy, jmx

I have some in-memory storage I'd like to expose via JMX to monitor:

```
@Component
@CompileStatic
@ManagedResource(
    objectName = 'bean:name=PageFragmentRepository',
    currencyTimeLimit = 15
)

class EmbeddedPageFragmentRepository implements PageFragmentRepository {

    private final Map<String, Map<String, PageFragment>> storage = new ConcurrentHashMap<>()

    @ManagedOperation(description = 'All fragments')
    @Override
    List<PageFragment> findAll() {
        return storage.values().stream().flatMap { it.values() }.collect(toList())
    }
}
```

I can see the bean on `jconsole`, but then I try to call the operation when the `storage` is non-empty, I get:

```
ClassNotFoundException: c.i.w.g.p.f.e.PageFragment
```

This is my class, so I tried configuring the classpath when calling `jconsole`:

```
jconsole -J-Djava.class.path=$JAVA_HOME/lib/jconsole.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar:/path/to/my/boot/app.jar 2345
```

This results in `ClassNotFound: GroovyObject` (yes, I'm using Groovy). This means that despite I added the Spring Boot JAR to the classpath, still all the classes from dependant libraries packaged into it are not visible.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong? How can I see the result of the operation  without `ClassNotFoundException`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `PageFragment` is within the module that generated `app.jar` I don't see why it wouldn't work; If it doesn't, it's placed in *a* lib of the *fat* jar and there is no chance for JConsole to find it there.

That being said, all that does not really matter. I wouldn't return any complex object such as that `PageFragment` of yours with JMX. JConsole has no way to handle custom objects in the UI anyway so you'll get no benefit from calling that method there.

Comment: That might explain why I never really got into JMX until now - seems like pretty old and limited thing; I ended up exposing the data I need via REST endpoints instead - *way* simpler, expecially with Spring.